# When zooming out marker changes position In Swift 4

Tags: swift, google-maps

I also tried ground overlay but it doesn't work

I didn't find any solution please help.
Anybody know the solution of this?

```
for state in self.asset {

    let state_marker = GMSMarker()

    self.appTitle = state.appName    
    if state.appName == "AssetHistory"{
        path.add(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(state.Latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(state.Longitude)))
        bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path)
        if self.asset.first?.Latitude as CGFloat! == state.Latitude && self.asset.first?.Longitude as CGFloat! == state.Longitude
        {
            state_marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(state.Latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(state.Longitude))
            state_marker.icon = UIImage(named: "arrow_blue")
            state_marker.title = "Start"
            bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(state_marker.position)
        }
        if self.asset.last?.Latitude as CGFloat! == state.Latitude && self.asset.last?.Longitude as CGFloat! == state.Longitude
        {
            state_marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(state.Latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(state.Longitude))            
            state_marker.icon = UIImage(named: "arrow_red")
            state_marker.title = "End"
            bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(state_marker.position)
        }
    }else{
        path.removeAllCoordinates()
        state_marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(state.Latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(state.Longitude))
        let im = UIImage(named: state.Direction)
        state_marker.icon = self.imageWithImage(image: im!, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
        state_marker.title = "\(state.AssetName)"
        bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(state_marker.position)
    }
    state_marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    state_marker.tracksViewChanges = true
    state_marker.map = self.mapView
    state_marker.userData = state_marker.title    
}
```

[image: marker are not in position]

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Just re set the coordinates of state_marker after zoom in or zoom out.
`state_marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(state.Latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(state.Longitude))`

Comment: func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {

        for marker in self.markers {
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(marker.position.latitude), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(marker.position.longitude))
            marker.map = mapView
            
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Problem is from your markers groundAnchor, map is drawing marks correctly but you should set each marker groundAnchor according to its image.

> The ground anchor specifies the point in the icon image that is
> anchored to the marker's position on the Earth's surface. This point
> is specified within the continuous space [0.0, 1.0] x [0.0, 1.0],
> where (0,0) is the top-left corner of the image, and (1,1) is the
> bottom-right corner. If the image has non-zero alignmentRectInsets,
> the top-left and bottom-right mentioned above refer to the inset
> section of the image.